# How do you connect alternators in series?

Tags: generator

What does the circuit diagram of three phase generators connected in **series** look like?

I know they are usually connected in parallel for obvious reasons.

Comment: It depends on what access you have to the output windings.

Comment: Give more details regarding the winding configuration, voltage,power rating and internal impedance/regulation.

Answer (score 1):

If the alternator shafts are coupled together, the rotor windings could be connected in series as shown below. Obviously the three terminals of the neutral connection on one alternator would need to be accessible. This is not something that can be done with the alternators driving loads. They would need to start together and have their fields adjusted if they have wound fields.

A delta connection could be made in a similar way by reconnecting both ends of all three windings of each machine.

Obviously, the voltage will doubled unless the machines are operated at a lower speed than they are designed for. When you say "usually connected in parallel," that is a gross understatement.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You really can't at your level, not without precise machining and alignments. Your best bet is to rectify your voltage and boost it with a converter if you're looking for more voltage, or parallel them AFTER the diodes for more current. This way the diodes on the outputs will prevent backfeeding the other alternator.